# Can I create a panel-like thing on Windows with Python?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pywin32

Sorry for the vague title, couldn't come up with anything more informative %)

What I want is a 5px horizontal panel on the top of the screen that I can draw on (and, possible, handle clicks on too).

One of the following features would be awesome (although I understand it's probably not really possible to combine both of them):

- the panel should be just like the Windows's own taskbar, i.e., maximized windows should not overlap it, but start below it instead
- the panel should show in fullscreen apps too

Is it possible to do this in Python?

Thanks.

Comment: Windows taskbar does not show when an app goes full screen. You mean maximized rather than full screen. The control you are describing is called an [app bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144177(VS.85).aspx). I'd be very surprised if there was a good Python wrapper to app bars. Expect to write your own using raw win32. Much pain awaits.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that's exactly what I said: I want it to *either* be like taskbar (show when window maximized) OR show in fullscreen.

Comment: A full screen window hides the task bar. Anyway, what you need is something that eats into the desktop's work area. As I said, on Windows that is called an app bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The "how" part depends on the GUI library you choose for which there are many options, but most people will recommend the following two: wxPython or PySide which is Qt for Python.

PySide has good documentation and [tutorials](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/PySide_Tutorials_by_Experience_Level).

What you will want to do is create a QMainWindow instance and set the WindowFlags to your requirements. You probably want the following combination `Qt::Window | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint`.

Something like this:

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class Form(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create the Qt Application
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # Create and show the form
    form = Form()
    form.show()
    # Run the main Qt loop
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note, that there is a limit to the "staying on top" nature of such windows. There are Win32-specific ways to fight it and get even higher, but such requirement would be a design error.

Comment: I don't see how this would reduce the work area of the desktop in the way that taskbar and app bars do.

Comment: The way I understood the question, he wanted an always-on top window rather than a taskbar in that sense (he said applications should start "below" it)

Comment: Yes, that's an app bar rather than an always on top window. A maximised window would be underneath your always on top window.

Comment: No that's not the same. A regular window can be turned into an always on top window without it eating away the desktop work area as an app bar does. OP said in the question and his comment that he wants his window on top even the maximised windows.

Comment: From the question: "maximized windows should not overlap it, but start below it instead"

Comment: Not overlapping means that this window should stay on top.

Comment: No. Not overlapping means that the bounding regions do not intersect. That's entirely different.